# Synchronize local folder with remote folder Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, php, fuel-sdk, content-builder

I used to do a sync operation among local and remote folders in Content Classic using a [php library](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP/). However now in Content Builder not sure if there's any library ( not plain API calls) that can keep in sync a couple of folders.

I already have migrated/imported the folders from Content Classic into Content Builder. However I'm looking for some automated process instead of manual interactions using the UI provided.

I know there's an API content but I'm not looking to start from scratch. Have you used any library similar to the one I mentioned but for Content Builder? I have seen [this one](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk) but seems is for a different purpose.