# Content Builder FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, content-builder

I see there are different flavors on the FuelSDK libraries. May I know which one is used for interact with Content Builder? Seems most of them are used for the Classic Content tool.

I have inquired with the FuelSDK-PHP site and seems the library lacks of support for Content Builder. I'm trying now with the python flavor, not sure if I will get something useful but giving a try, better than nothing.

Is someone using any FuelSDK flavor to interact with Content Builder? I need to update/create files using some code instead of the *gui*.

Find [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/247597/synchronize-local-folder-with-remote-folder-content-builder) what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a local folder copy first,

Use [this call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm) to get that done:

POST /asset/v1/content/assets/query

Take care of saving the ids somewhere to use them later when need to update remote files.

Then do a patch request using [this call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm#detail_patchAsset)

PATCH /asset/v1/content/assets/{id}

That will do what You are looking for.